# How to save a view using federated queries across two projects?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking to save a view which uses federated queries (from a MySQL Cloud SQL connection) between two projects. I'm receiving two different errors (depending on which project I try to save in).

If I try to save in the project containing the dataset I get error:

> Not found: Connection my-connection-name

If I try to save in the project that contains the connection I get error:

> Not found: Dataset my-project:my_dataset

My example query that crosses projects looks like:

```
SELECT
  bq.uuid,
  sql.item_id,
  sql.title
FROM
  `project_1.my_dataset.psa_v2_202005` AS bq
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  EXTERNAL_QUERY( 'project_2.us-east1.my-connection-name',
    '''SELECT item_id, title
  FROM items''') AS sql
ON
  bq.looks_info.query_item.item_id = sql.item_id
```

The documentation at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#known_issues_and_limitations doesn't mention any limitations here.

Is there a way around this so I can save a view using an external connection from one project and dataset from another?

Comment: Hello! What are the locations of your: connection, BigQuery table and Cloud SQL instance (must be in the same location)? According to the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#create_a_connection_resource) the connection resource should be created in the same location as the Cloud SQL instance (with the exceptions mentioned in the document). Have you followed "Before you begin" [section](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#before_you_begin)?

Comment: I wasn't able to create the connection until I specified the same location. But I'm not sure the connection and dataset location are the same. It looks like my dataset is in the generic "US" location and the connection is in us-east1. Are you saying this is incompatible? I don't see where this is mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: thanks for providing me with additional information. I've added the answer with describing the issue and providing solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your BigQuery table is located in `US` and your MySQL data source is located in `us-east1`. BigQuery automatically chooses to run the query in the location of your BigQuery table (i.e. in `US`), however, your Cloud MySQL is in `us-east1` and that's why your query fails. Therefore the BigQuery table and Cloud SQL instance, must be in the same location in order for this query to succeed.

The solution for this kind of cases is moving your BigQuery dataset to the same location as your Cloud SQL instance manually by following the steps explained in detail in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets). However, the `us-east1` is not currently supported for copying datasets. Thus, I will recommend you to create a new connection in one of the locations mentioned in the documentation.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.

Comment: Hi Ines, is there is way to connect to the Cloud SQL instance which is different gcp project. For example, in Project A the cloud sql is created in US region, and I want to bring the SQL data to the bigquery in project B using an external data source connection.